# Mac User connecting to Exchange Server

Tags: email, exchange

I am a longtime mac user, and the world of Microsoft Exchange is totally foreign to me.  At my school I have an account on an exchange server where I have a few years' worth of email threads...  As my last semester is coming to an end, I am trying to archive my email history over my academic career there. I need to somehow get copies of my inboxes and outboxes to my mac.  Is there a script I can run to forward them all to myself or something?  what is the best way to go about getting my mail history over to my mac?

Comment: Please be aware that answers here will focus on the Mac side of things (and not on how to export from Microsoft Exchange for instance).

Comment: How do you access your e-mail now? Mail on Mac can connect to Exchange accounts easily and you could then save or export your e-mails from there.

Comment: @Lizzan: Actually I can access my exchange from my iOS device, which is great.  and I even have copies of my INBOX.  *however* my outbox (mails sent via the exchange server) are missing from my collection.  How can I get copies of these?

Comment: @patrix:  where would I ask on how to export from Exchange?

Comment: @kent Do you not have a "Sent"-folder in your account?

Comment: Super User might be suitable for Exchange question, but check the FAQ there.

Comment: @Lizzan: yes, I have a sent folder.  However when I am not connected to the exchange server it is empty.  So I am looking for a way to somehow get copies of the contents of my sent folder so that when I no longer *can* connect to the exchange server I still have an archive of my mail. A script which sends me the contents of sent mail I guess would be an ugly hack...

Comment: There is in Mail an export function in the menu under Mailboxes -> Export mailbox. I'm unsure of exactly what that does, but perhaps you could try that on your sent folder (while connected). There is an "Import Mailboxes..." menu choice in the File menu as well that might work to re-import your sent mail.

Comment: Exchange is just Microsofts version of IMAP.  Set your account up on your Mac, then copy the the messages from a server folder to a local folder.  iPhones don't typically synch the entire folder, instead using Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Mail Days to Synch